# Pinescript: Pivot line plotting issue

Tags: pivot, pine-script, pine-script-v5, tradingview-api, pine-script-v4

[Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/12Xmw.png)

Hi I have written this code to display pivot, but pivot lines (red,orange,yellow) on the current bar seem weird like the photo above, and I want to make it straight or continued just as the pivot lines on the previous bars. Their values just suddenly change from the previous to the current bar. My intention is displaying pivots from the yesterday's data throughout the bars today. Could anyone please help me to fix this, please? The version is @5.

```
pma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', hlc3[1])
diff = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', hl2[1])
pr = pma-diff
ph = pma+pr
pl = pma-pr
plot(pma, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.orange, 0))
plot(ph, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.red,0))
plot(pl, linewidth=2, color=color.new(color.yellow,0))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the lookahead parameter

```
pma = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', hlc3[1],barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
diff = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', hl2[1], barmerge.gaps_off, barmerge.lookahead_on)
```

Source: [https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request{dot}security](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#fun_request%7Bdot%7Dsecurity)

Comment: Thank yo so much